# Stored selection data from json in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

The selection value is retrieve from the json file. I would like to know how to retrieve the value of the branch only and store in a variable..can anyone help?
This because I need to add another functionality in another `js` file and for that i need to retrieve the branch value from the selection.

Selection.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Acc Type
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="accTypeSel"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        async:true,
        url:'ref/jsonData.json',
        success:function(data){
            for (var i=0;i<data.accList.length;i++)
            {
                var $option=$('<option />');
                $option.attr('value',data.accList[i].code,data.accList[i].branch);
                $option.text(data.accList[i].code+" ("+data.accList[i].branch+")");
                $('#accTypeSel').append($option);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Json file

```
{
"accList":[
    {
        "code":"1234",
        "branch":"Branch1"
    },
    {
        "code":"4321",
        "branch":"Branch2"
    },
    {
        "code":"1111",
        "branch":"Branch3"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML part:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Acc Type
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="accTypeSel">
            <option value=""> </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Replace your script by this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON( "jsonData.json", function(data) {
    $.each( data.accList, function() {
        $('#accTypeSel').append("<option value='"+ this.branch +"'>"+ this.branch+" </option>" ) ;
    });
}); 
});
</script>
```

Navigate to your JSON file correctly inside the getJSON function as yours 'ref/jsonData.json'. Also use jquery 2.

Comment: How can I store it in a a variable?

Comment: inside $.each function you can see there is a variable: this.branch 
this.branch contains your branch from json file. You can store this into your variable by this way:

    var yourVariable = this.branch ;

Comment: $.each( data.accList, function() {
        var variable =  this.branch;
    });

Comment: Why do your code display branch only??where is the code?

Comment: "data.accList " contains both branch and code . If you want code then you have to use "this.code"  :)

Comment: how about displaying it both?

Comment: Ok, I am giving you a code which will display code inside value and branch  as branch name.

$('#accTypeSel').append("<option value='"+ **this.code** +"'>"+ this.branch+" </option>" ) ; 

see ? I have changed the value with code ?

Comment: No.It's Not working..how can I show both code and branch

Answer (score 0):

Use a change function on the select element.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accTypeSel").change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can i add a value in the variable?

Comment: `selected` is the variable.